# multiple summernotes to differend textareas

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, summernote

I want to point my multiple summernote textareas to each point to a different textarea for multilanguage purposes.

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
   onChange: function() {
     $("#stage").val($(".summernote").code());
   },
    height: 200,
    tabsize: 2,
    lang: 'nl-NL'
});
```

Where stage should actually be a array to send to a php file for storing in a database.

this is my current html (using bootstrap)

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="description[]">Bericht:</label>
   <textarea cols="40" name="description[]" rows="4" class="form-control summernote" placeholder="Bericht"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="stage">stage:</label>
  <textarea cols="40" name="stage" rows="4" class="form-control" id="stage" placeholder="stage"></textarea>
</div>
```

I understand that having stage for an id isn't going to stand for a solution because of its uniqueness. But I'd like to use name="stage[]" for saving it into a database.

I have searched the web for a similar solution, but I haven't found one yet. I lack a bit of experience in jQuery to solve this on my own, so I hope you guys/girls can give me a go.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i placed a counter inside the each element, so  I can identify the fields.

this is my code:

```
$('.summernote').each(function(i, obj) { 
i++;
$(obj).summernote({
  onChange: function() {
      $("#stage_"+i).val($("#description_"+i).code());
      //alert(i);
  }
});
});
```

Feel free to let me know if there are better approaches, I'm open to learn!

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, your code doesn't look work. You don't need to increase `i` manually.

I think your html has mulple following structures:

```
<div class="summernote">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="staged"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

If so, you can write like this:

```
$('.summernote').each(function(i, obj) {
  var stage$ = $(obj).find('.stage');
  $(obj).find('.description').summernote({
    onChange: function(contents) {
      stage$.val(contents);
    }
  });
});
```

You can make this without `id`.
BTW, selecting DOM is not good for performance and `onChange` callback pass `contents` over as parameter.